# Koltin return null if value is null else

Tags: kotlin

I work with some business logic written in Kotlin. I've got such a case in my method - I check a value for null, and if it IS null - I want to return null, else do some logic. My version looks like:

```
fun calculateFoo(parameter: SomeObject?): ReturnObject? = 
    if (parameter == null) null
    else performCalculation(parameter)
```

Literally "If value is null then return itself else process it".
Normally, we do something if value is NOT null, like elvis operator, but here is "reversed" logic.
Is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `?.` operator in combination with `let`.

```kotlin
fun calculateFoo(parameter: SomeObject?): ReturnObject? = 
    parameter?.let { performCalculation(it) }
```

Answer (score 7):

Taking a step back, if you make this an extension function with non-null parameter, it leads to more natural use at its call site.

```
fun SomeObject.calculateFoo(): ReturnObject = 
    performCalculation(this)


val nullable: SomeObject? = ...
val result = nullable?.calculateFoo()
```

I think it's better for code clarity for a function not to simply return null for a null argument, because it masks nullability at the call site, where a `?.` call would suffice and keep the code clear about the possible null return value.
The semantics of your function as-is allow a useless argument to be passed for a useless result.

Granted, I understand your example is contrived, and there are cases where there are multiple arguments or where a null argument only leads to a useless result under certain circumstances, in which case the `?.let` answer would be more appropriate.

Comment: I like this approach.  Leads to more readable code.

Comment: Just to add to this, if `performCalculation` is our own function, we can directly make that an extension on `SomeObject` and get rid of this `calculateFoo` function.